# Reverse read xml file in php

Tags: php, xml, reverse

This is my php code

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("data/listings.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach($xml->children() as $listings){
 echo "<div class='col-md-4 top-text'>";
 echo "<a href='?p=single&n=" . $listings->time . "'><img src='thumbnails/" . $listings->images . ".jpg' class='img-responsive' alt=''></a>";
 echo "<h5 class='top'><a href='?p=single&n=" . $listings->time . "'>" . $listings->title . "</a></h5>";
 echo "</div>";
}
```

I can not read from end to start using the below code.

```
foreach(array_reverse($xml->children()) as $listings){
 echo "<div class='col-md-4 top-text'>";
 echo "<a href='?p=single&n=" . $listings->time . "'><img src='thumbnails/" . $listings->images . ".jpg' class='img-responsive' alt=''></a>";
 echo "<h5 class='top'><a href='?p=single&n=" . $listings->time . "'>" . $listings->title . "</a></h5>";
 echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: Please format your question

Answer (score 2):

When you call [`children()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) on a SimpleXMLElement, you get another SimpleXMLElement back and not an array, so you can't call `array_reverse()` on it.  A simple way round this is to use a `for()` loop instead...

```
for ( $i=$xml->children()->count()-1; $i>=0; $i-- )    {
    $list = $xml->children()[$i];
    echo "<div class='col-md-4 top-text'>";
    echo "<a href='?p=single&n=" . $listings->time . "'><img src='thumbnails/" . $listings->images . ".jpg' class='img-responsive' alt=''></a>";
    echo "<h5 class='top'><a href='?p=single&n=" . $listings->time . "'>" . $listings->title . "</a></h5>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

The reason why you can use it in a `foreach()` normally is that it implements Traversable, which allows you to process it using various methods as though it was an array.